# AWK - Replacing Value Of Selected Column Destroys Output Format

Tags: awk, outputformat

I have a .csv file with the following format.
`id|name|date`

I am using the following Awk command to change a specific column in a row and it works.
`awk -F "|" '{$"'"$col"'"="'"$val"'";}1' filename.csv`

I wanna save the output , however the format is destroyed.

What I want :  `100|James|2015`

What I get : `100 James 2015`

How do I avoid the second one, and get the first one ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set the OFS, the Output Field Separator like in this example:

```
awk -F\| -v OFS=\| '{print $1, $2, $3 }'  test.psv
```

- The `-v OFS=\|` assigns the `OFS` variable the values `|`. It is an alternative to a `BEGIN { OFS = "|" }` block.
- The `|` needs to be protected from the shell, since the meaning an shell level is piping of one commands output into the input of another command. Using `"|"` or `\|` are two ways to do so.

Comment: Works perfectly fine, thank you very much. Care to explain the difference between "|" and '\|' ? Also the '-v' ?

Answer (score 2):

Never let shell variables expand to become part of the body of an awk script:

```
awk -F "|" '{$"'"$col"'"="'"$val"'";}1' filename.csv
```

as it opens you up to insidious errors given various values of those shell variables. Instead populate awk variables from the shell variables and use the awk variables within the script:

```
awk -F "|" -v col="$col" -v val="$val" '{$col=val}1' filename.csv
```

wrt your specific question, though, awk reconstructs the record when you assign a value to a field so you need the OFS to have the same value as the FS:

```
awk -v col="$col" -v val="$val" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {$col=val}1' filename.csv
```

Comment: You're welcome. I highly recommend the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins if you're going to be doing any more text manipulation on UNIX.